# Python and Django Source Code Navigation in Emacs

Tags: python, django, emacs

I am wondering if there is a way to to navigate Python(Django) code in Emacs similar to how one can `M-.` for Common Lisp code when using SLIME.

I have installed ELPY and a mode called `python-django`. However, they do not seem to provide this functionality.

I am particularly interested in doing this why developing using Django. However, even navigation for standalone Python projects would be nice.

Comment: there are a number of packages with xref backends for python, personally I use `anaconda-mode` but there are other server based ones like `lsp-emacs`, `eglot`, etc.  It should be pretty easy to find this info.  Alternatively, there are numerous tags-based xref backends that would work

Comment: Thanks. Are any of them expected to work for Django?

Comment: Django is just a python library right? `anaconda-mode`'s xref function should jump to any python package source (you need to install some python introspection packages like `jedi`, etc -- all listed on the site I'm sure).  If you are want to jump to other assests like javascript, css, html, or whatever I would just tag the project using something like `universal-ctags`, `global`, or `etags` and use the TAGS/GTAGS with the appropriate emacs backend and that should let you jump to multilanguage project locations.

Comment: that `python-django` package you mention says it supports easy `etags` generation (emacs comes bundled with an `etags` program). Note xref backends run in term like company backends, so if one doesn't support an operation then the next one should be attempted, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I shall look into it. None of it is familiar.

Answer (score 0):

I will give [dumb-jump](https://github.com/jacktasia/dumb-jump) a chance.

It is not as fancy as other go-to-definition methods, as it only searchs for some predefined regex in your project. But it simply works most of the time, and you can add your own regex if you need them.